# YouTube-dl to download and name videos from Reddit

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl, praw

I have been able to hack together my first script ! What it does is that it goes to a sub-reddit, gets the top submission, and then download the videos using youtube-dl.
and it works !

```
import praw
import os

user_agent = "mybot"

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)

submissions = r.get_subreddit('unexpectedjihad').get_top(limit=10)
urls = []
def yt() :
    for x in submissions:
        urls.append(str(x.url))
    return urls

yt_urls = yt()

for item in yt_urls:
    print "downloading..." + " "
    os.system("youtube-dl" + " " + item)
    print "done"
```

What I want to do next is to get Youtube-dl to set the file name the same as the title of the reddit submission.

I get very confused thinking about how I should go about matching the title video the video file. How should I go about this ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme), you want to pass -o to youtube-dl, E.G.:

```
for item in submissions:
   os.system('youtube-dl -o {}.%(ext)s {}'.format(item.title, item.url))
```

However, given the problems that may arise from this, embedding YDL directly might be simpler, E.G.:

```
import youtube_dl
# ... reddit stuff here ...

for item in submissions:
   # see options at https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L89
   ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': item.title + '.%(ext)s'}
   with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
       ydl.download([item.url, ])
```

Comment: Note: you need "s" after (ext), according to the docs. I.e., `%(ext)s` instead of `%(ext)`.

Comment: Also, you should handle the fact that the title will have spaces in it. I think you need to pass separate arguments for this to work.

Comment: I'd personally incorporate youtube-dl directly rather than call system()... Amending answer in a second.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkR. this really helped. Your code made me learn a couple of things too ! :)